# Python - reading History file of chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, google-chrome, python-3.10

I try using the following code to read chrome history file

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT url FROM urls")
urls = cursor.fetchall()
print('\n'.join(urls))
```

if I run the code I get `Process finished with exit code 0`
I tried it with chinook.db
every website , guide , tutorial shows the same way with tweaks added nothing worked .
tried using python3.10 & python3.9

I use windows10 , created VM with win10 and it works there any suggestions?

I placed history file in another folder and chrome still has its history , rechecked user , path seems chrome takes his history from some another place

i used chinook.db and it worked , obviously chrome history file isn't empty but nothing prints

opened history.db using DB browser and it seems to be empty , but chrome shows otherwise

I have deleted History file from chrome now i get the following error ( visited few sites to make sure it's not empty )

```
    cursor.execute("SELECT url FROM urls")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: urls
```

Comment: Copy/pasted and it works fine here. Only had to change user, close the browser and change the print statement, as it returns a tuple.

Comment: I closed the browser and tried again but nothing shows like everything executed but no result

Comment: if i try debug it i get sqlite3.connection.interfaceerror

Comment: Sorry man, it must be a problem on your system. It works fine here. :-)

Comment: I created VMware with windows10 , it works there , but I still have the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the issue ,
I deleted C:\Users{User}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome folder
then relaunched chrome , and everything works.